# help with php FOREACH loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

can some please tell me what's wrong with the bellow foreach php loop.

```
foreach ($_POST[sortlist] as $key => $value) 
{
    $sql = "UPDATE sortable 
            SET color_order = " . mysql_real_escape_string($key) . " 
            WHERE id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($value);

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I keep getting warning: invalid argument suplied foreach() in ....
when i upload to server

Thanks

Comment: Please post the content of the $_POST['sortlist'] array (If it is really an array)

Answer (score 4):

`$_POST['sortlist']` is probably not an array. Try `print_r($_POST)` to see what do you have there.

Answer (score 3):

Try change `$_POST[sortlist]` to `$_POST['sortlist']`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $_POST[sortlist] is not an array. This is probably what you are trying to do:

```
foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue) {
    $sql = "update sortable set color_order = ".mysql_real_escape_string($varname)."   where id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($varvalue);
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 }
```

Or if $_POST['sortlist'] is an array, try this:

```
foreach ($_POST['sortlist'] as $varname => $varvalue) {
    $sql = "update sortable set color_order = ".mysql_real_escape_string($varname)."   where id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($varvalue);
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A tip: the error message refers to the foreach line. That only reads from one variable, $_POST[sortlist], which isn't modified inside the loop. So you can ignore all the SQL stuff; it's not relevant to your problem. Reduce the problem to the smallest possible piece of code that still has an error. That will help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use  `mysql_query` , its very insecure and is deprecated .

start using `mysqli_query`, is not as safe as `PDO` but will be lot better.

Answer (score -1):

Please, for the love of the internet, don't built an SQL query yourself. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).